# Python code for calculating the increase in a number over a period of months if it increases by 10% each month

Tags: python, calculator

i am trying to get the percentage increase over a period of selected months .i cant seem to get a hold on how to make  use of the current month value in calculating for the new month and summing all togther .

```
NOC  = int(input('Please enter the number of chickens : '))
MONTHS = int(input('Please enter the number of months for the estimate : '))
FCE = NOC*10*MONTHS/100

if NOC == '' and MONTHS =='' :
    print('please Enter a value for month and year')


else:
    print('Your Result',FCE)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for compound increase then you need to iterate over each month and use the last months value to increase

```
NOC  = int(input('Please enter the number of chickens : '))

MONTHS = int(input('Please enter the number of months for the estimate : ')) 

for month in range(0, MONTHS):
   NOC = NOC + (NOC*0.1)

print(NOC)
```